# Bluetooth speakers with USB charging and line in (aux input)

Tags: bluetooth, speakers

I am looking for a bluetooth speaker that can:

- charge through USB, so I don't have to worry about not losing a proprietary charger
- connect through a 3.5 mm line in (aux input) - so I can use it as a regular speaker with any device

The budget is 150 Euro maximum

Yet an important question is: if the speaker has the USB charging feature, then it can charge with any USB charger or maybe some of such speakers can only charge when using their own USB charger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Ultimate Ears MEGABOOM** is a really good option.

Now on Amazon UK for £127.99 **https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00PDUE8TG**

- Charges via typical Micro USB.
- Has a 3.5mm aux input

But in general, it is a solid good speaker with awesome battery life and great sound.

As for your USB charging question: if it uses the same connection it will usually charge with any such connection if something it just won't charge that fast.

Comment: It is just a bit more than 150 Euro but most likely the best option these days